# React Native: How to align all items horizontally, using FlexBox, with some space between them?

Tags: html, css, react-native

How can I use Flex-box to align these items horizontally, with some space between them?
This is my code:

```
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.header} >{title}</Text>
            <Card style={styles.card} elevation={3}>
                <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>Pakken Cola Zero</Text>
                <Text style={styles.separator}>|</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchableOpacity} onPress={() => alert('+')}>
                    <Text>+</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchableOpacity} onPress={() => alert('-')}>
                    <Text>-</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Card>
            <Button title='Add to firebase' onPress={() => addToFirebase(title)}></Button>
          </View>  

CSS i have right now:  

    export default StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    header: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      fontSize: 24,
      marginTop: 25,
    },
    card: {
      margin: 30,
      padding: 50,
      width: '83%',
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      alignItems: 'center',
      flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    itemTitle: {
      
    },
    separator: {
      color: '#b0b5b1',
    },
    touchableOpacity: {
      padding: 25
    }
  });
```

This is the result I want (made in paint so not precise...):

How can I achieve this using Flex-box?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5GUx.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxX5W.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was not able to fix this with `Card` but it is easy to do it with a `View`

Have a look [here](https://snack.expo.io/@alentoma/hor-items-stackoverflow)

- Note: when you try to build something like that try to separate those
  component with `View` or something else. `Text` dose not really
  follow `%` styles values sometimes. eg when the screen orientation
  changes.

---

Comment: Thanks this works! Good tip, I'm new to React Native so I'll use View more ;). I'll try to fix it with Card myself. I'll also see what each line actually changes so I can better understand flexbox!

Comment: Im glad i could help.